# Next.js website random freeze/502 error, resumes for hours after reload/restart pm2 TRIED EVERYTHING

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js, pm2

once again desperate enough to post on stackoverflow, after spending days on this issue.

Issue:

- Two production websites, both very similar (next.js 13.2.4) hosted on same server, experience random freezes without throwing any error in their pm2 logs (besides FetchError: request to https://... failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN) which basically means the site is down.

Other websites are fine on the same server, even other next.js ones run fine
I do not know how to reproduce it freezing, it appears to be random (best type)

What I have tried:

- checking nginx logs (not helpful) "connect() failed (111: Unknown error) "
- yarn upgrade, went from next.js 13.1 to 13.2.4
- deleted node_modules & .next folders, reinstalled everything, deployed, freezes after 2-3 hours
- rebooted server
- changed node version from 19.7 to 18 to 16, same

Both sites have been working for months without ever freezing/crashing...
Their code base isn't wrong, their staging versions on the same server don't freeze/crash, but they have do have way less traffic. (1-2 visits/day compared to hundreds on the prod)

Everything is hosted on a ubuntu 22.04.2 Linux 5.15.0-67-generic on x86_64 kernel VPS with 4gb ram that is 60% used aprox.

The 'fix' is to use pm2 reload or restart and its back up in an instant, for now I have a cron job checking every minute if its down & pm2 reload's it back... Note: the pm2 list shows 'status online' when its frozen...

What I use to deploy it is "yarn build && pm2 delete prod_name && pm2 start yarn --name prod_name -- next start -p 3100 && pm2 save"

Please help this is driving me crazy and making me look bad.
Thanks!!!

Comment: The only thing that changes is that I use Webmin admin panel and it applies package updates, otherwise its pretty much the same code/server that has been working for months...

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm facing similar issues since i started using pm2 in cluster mode..

Comment: haven't figured it out, the cron job is still checking every minute, but in the past 4 days they haven't crashed, so it seems to have solved itself?